# Sql Rows to Column help for beginer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm here to learn. I need a best practice used for the following scenario. No sql experience...

Table:

```
Id   Second_id   Wanted_rows
10   61          Blue
10   65          999-JHD
10   70          Gasoline
11   61          Red
11   65          786-FDX
11   70          Disel
```

I need to get this:

```
Car_id   Color   Engine     Plate
10       Blue    Gasoline   999-JHD
11       Red     Disel      786-FDX
```

Comment: Hi @gummyBeerCan what have you tried so far? W3C is a great starting point for SQL as well. I'd say you need either a double join or pivot.

Comment: No clue where to start... :(

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select t1.id, t1.wanted_rows as color, t2.wanted_rows as engine, t3.wanted_rows as Plate  
  from data t1
    inner join data t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.second_id = 70
    inner join data t3 on t3.id = t1.id and t3.second_id = 65
  where  t1.second_id = 61
order by t1.id
```

or

```
select t1.id, t1.wanted_rows as color,
(select wanted_rows from data where id = t1.id and second_id = 70) as engine,
(select wanted_rows from data where id = t1.id and second_id = 65) as plate
  from data t1 
  where  t1.second_id = 61 
order by t1.id
```

where data you have to put your table name.

Comment: Thanks.. So no need for advanced CASE function..

Comment: Yes you could use case too, or pivot but this is a simple to understand solution

Comment: Can you help me reduce this selects into a CASE?

Comment: ( select a from b where b.id=100 and b.nd_id=98) "First column", ( select a from b where b.id=100 and b.nd_id=97) "Second column"...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (and I've knocked this up in Notepad)..

```
SELECT Car_id as a.id, Color As a.Wanted_rows, Engine As b.Wanted_rows,  Plate As b.Plate
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA
```

Then look at groups and so forth from there